# How to enable drag and drop with trackpad in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: trackpad

About 80% of the time when I try to drag objects or select text by using the left-click button and the trackpad, it doesn't work. Instead what happens is I move the cursor, but nothing happens (objects don't move, text isn't selected, etc.) So instead what I have to do is double tap on the trackpad and then hope that I'm able to drag as far as I need to before my finger gets to the end of the trackpad. The other 20% of the time, I can drag and drop no problem. Perhaps there is there some sort of toggle I'm not aware of? I'd like to be able to drag and drop 100% of the time.

Comment: If you can double tap and drag, then if your finger arrives at the end of the trackpad, you can put a second finger on the trackpad, remove the first finger and continue dragging. It's not a solution but a workaround though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you have to do :

1. Click on the **Settings Icon** in the top-right-most of the panel (on the right of **Time**)
2. Click on **System Settings**
3. Go to, **Mouse & Touchpad**
4. Check the **Tap to Click** and you're done !